# Spring-webflow error popup tweak

Tags: popup, spring-webflow-2

There is a link in a spring-webflow2 based application which start different flows. Flows are shown in popup (popup=true). If the session is expired or server is unavailable, the spring-webflow shows small empty popup with "Ajax Request Error" tooltip shown on mouse over. Is it possible to tweak the popup in order to give the user an ability to either re-login or to just close the popup and retry the request?

EDIT: Or maybe some ideas how to force Spring-Dojo to make a redirect to login page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the session is gone and so is the conversation/flow in it. So there's no easy way to make the popup work again, because the conversation or flow state must be restored. I think the best you could achieve would be to somehow convince Dojo to redirect back to the login url.